# Centering content in a th from a datatables table

Tags: html, css, datatables

I'm trying to understand how I can have my th tags that have a class assigned to them called "nosortable" to have its content of that cell be perfectly centered whether its a checkbox or text. I tried applying a padding-right of 0 but that took it all off. Are their any ideas?

```
<table id="basicTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
    <thead class="">
        <tr>
            <th class="nosortable center"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" /></th>
            <th class="center">ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th class="nosortable center">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
         <tr>
                <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" class="tablecheck" data-id="1"/></td>
                <td class="center">1</td>
                <td>My name</td>
                <td>myemail@email.com</td>
                <td>testuser</td>
                <td>Owner</td>
                <td>Active</td>
                <td class="center">
                    <a data-original-title="Edit" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="tooltips"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                    <a data-original-title="Delete" href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="delete-row tooltips"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>            
                </td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/cLzj4kL1/

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet add the following

```
table#basicTable th {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: That centers everything but what I"m trying to center.

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't have any styling - how can I know what it's supposed to look like?  Also, this has nothing to do with datatables.

Comment: If you notice in the first th tag has a checkbox as the column heading. Its pushed over to the left to make it NOT aligned with the rest of the checkboxes td's.